# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error when trying to send a message on my rails app. 
Please help me get it right. The conversations.html.erb file does not have any line 36 and 38. Here is the  error:

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
>             end
>                ^):    app/views/private/conversations/_conversation.html.erb:36: syntax
>   error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
>   app/views/private/conversations/_conversation.html.erb:38: syntax
>   error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
>   app/views/private/conversations/_open.js.erb:10:in
>   `_app_views_private_conversations__open_js_erb___4089549709349058989_70036360651440'
>   app/views/assignments/show/contact_user/message_form/_success.js.erb:8:in`
>   _app_views_assignments_show_contact_user_message_form__success_js_erb__1046129379162570439_70036360658520'
>   app/controllers/private/conversations_controller.rb:18:in `block (2
>   levels) in create'
>   app/controllers/private/conversations_controller.rb:16:in`create'

I have attached the controller and the _conversation.html.erb file.Any help offered shall be highly appreciated. Thank you

```
class Private::ConversationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    recipient_id = Assignment.find(params[:assignment_id]).user.id
    @conversation = Private::Conversation.new(sender_id: current_user.id,
      recipient_id: recipient_id)

    if @conversation.save
      Private::Message.create(user_id: current_user.id,
        conversation_id: @conversation.id,
        body: params[:message_body])

      add_to_conversations unless already_added?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render partial: 'assignments/show/contact_user/message_form/success'}
      end

    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render partial: 'assignments/show/contact_user/message_form/fail'}
      end
    end
  end  

  def close
    @conversation_id = params[:id].to_i
    session[:private_conversations].delete(@conversation_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def add_to_conversations
    session[:private_conversations] ||= []
    session[:private_conversations] << @conversation.id
  end

  def already_added?
    session[:private_conversations].include?(@conversation.id)
  end
end
```

```html
<% @recipient = private_conv_recipient(conversation) %>
<% @is_messanger = false %>

<li class="conversation-window"
  id="pc<%= conversation.id>"
  data-pconversation-user-name="<%= @recipient.name %>"
  data-turbolinks-permanent>

  <div class="panel panel-default" data-pconversation-id ="<%= conversation.id %>">
    <%= render 'private/conversations/conversation/heading', conversation: conversation %>
    <!-- Conversation window's content -->
    <div class="panel-body">
     <%= render 'private/conversations/conversation/messages_list', conversation: conversation %>
     <%= render 'private/conversations/conversation/new_message_form', conversation: conversation, user: user %>
   </div><!-- panel-body -->
  </div>
</li><!-- conversation-window -->
```

Comment: Read the message more carefully. It's about `app/views/private/conversations/_conversation.html.erb` file, not `conversations.html.erb`.

Comment: app/views/private/conversations/_conversation.html.erb

Comment: That is the file that I have posted, the conversations.html.erb does not exist, it is a typo. The right file is _conversation.html.erb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to close the tag

```
 pc<%= conversation.id>
```